# What is this type? "transaction abort"

Tags: erlang

Reading [mnesia docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#write-1), I see a return type for mnesia:write declared as:

```
write(Record) -> transaction abort | ok
```

What is this type `transaction abort`? I've never seen type made up of two atoms. I know there are parametrized types, but it would be `transaction(abort)`.

Any clues?

Comment: look this: http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#abort-1 This function must be called to the transaction failed.